# pseudocode input age, calculate max and average for java

Tags: java, pseudocode

Write a pseudo code algorithm which will input a series of people's
ages (as integers between 1 and 120 inclusive) and calculate the maximum and average
age. The average age should be calculated as a real number. Your algorithm should
continue to input age values until the user inputs a value of zero. This is a signal for the
algorithm to stop inputting the age, and to then output the average and maximum ages. If
the user enters an age that is invalid then your algorithm should continue to re-prompt the
user until they enter a valid age. Your algorithm should make good use of sub modules.
Note zero should not be included when determining the average or maximum age.

this is my practice question

i have come up with

```
main 

FOR 
age = inputAge <-prompt "enter age"
max = getMax <- age
sum = sum + age
average = getAverage <- sum, number of times input
END FOR
OUTPUT max, average

END MAIN

METHOD inputAge
IMPORT prompt
EXPORT age
    INPUT age
    WHILE age >= 120 AND age <= 0 DO
        OUTPUT "enter valid age"
        INPUT age

    END WHILE 
END 

METHOD getMax
IMPORT age
EXPORT max
    IF max < 0 THEN
    max = age
END

METHOD getAverage
IMPORT sum, number of times input
EXPORT average
    average = sum / number of times input
END
```

my problem is that im not quite sure how to input 1 to 120 and stop loop when 0 is input and getting number of times input so i can calculate the average. the for loop in the main is also a problem. i get what the question is asking but its just not getting together in my head. could i get help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, it would be far simpler to calculate the average after collecting all inputs and saving the biggest value until then as the maximum value. So, setting the sum and the max to 0 and creating a variable to count the number of inputs would be a nice start. I would do something like this:

```
main 

max = 0
sum = 0
count = 0

WHILE true 
age = inputAge <-prompt "enter age"
IF age == 0 THEN
    BREAK
END IF
IF age > max THEN
    max = age
END IF
sum = sum + age
count = count + 1
END WHILE
average = getAverage <- sum, count
IF count == 0 THEN
    OUTPUT "There was no input"
ELSE
    OUTPUT max, average
END IF

END MAIN

METHOD inputAge
IMPORT prompt
EXPORT age
    INPUT age
    WHILE age >= 120 AND age <= 0 DO
        OUTPUT "enter valid age"
        INPUT age

    END WHILE 
END

METHOD getAverage
IMPORT sum, number of times input
EXPORT average
    average = sum / number of times input
END
```